# How do I monitor or view the thread count of a certain process on AIX?

Tags: process, aix, threads

How do I monitor or view the thread count of a certain process on AIX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ps -o thcount -p <process id>
```

That would give you only the thread count.

Play with other field specifiers for the "-o" option (see 'man ps') for other info. For instance

```
ps -o pid,comm,user,thcount -p <process id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use this to see all the processes and their threads for a single user. Replace `USER_ID` with the user's ID. Don't replace `THREAD` with anything, use that literal string:

```
ps -flu USER_ID -o THREAD -m
```